# How to keep asking the user for a file

Tags: python, file-io

New programmer here, and well let me start off with the code I have.

```
try:
    f = input("Please type in the path to your file and press 'Enter'")
    file = open(f,'r')
except FileNotFoundError:
    f = input("File not found please try again.")
```

What I'm trying to accomplish, is if the user enters a wrong file, to keep asking the user to try again. Maybe I shouldn't be using try/except?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embed the statement inside a `while` loop. `break` if file is opened successfully.

```
while True:
    try:
        f = input("Please type in the path to your file and press 'Enter'")
        file = open(f, 'r')
        break
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('File not found')
```

NOTE: You may need to handle other exceptions like `IOError` (even though, there is a file, you may not possible to open it - because of permsssion, wrong file type, ..)

Comment: Thank you, I will do so! Though it's telling me I need to wait 8 minutes. Also if I wanted to target the IOError, then I would just make another exception for it right.

Comment: Another `except IOError:` if you want to handle `IOException` differently from `FileNotFoundError`.  or `except (FileNotFoundError, IOException):` if you want to handle them same way.